# Jquery in separate file using codeigniter & php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I understand that you can put your $(document).ready() code into separate files from the html, however as part of my javascript I use some calls back to codeigniter PHP functions such as site_url() which doesn't work when part of a separate .js file.

Here's an example:

login_page.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo site_url('scripts') . '/' . 'app/login_page.js'; ?>"></script> 
<div id="loginForm" class="prepend-2 column span-21">
    <p class="tips"></p>
    <div class="column span-10">
        <dl>                
            <dt><label>Email:</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="text" /></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="column span-10 last">
        <dl>                
            <dt><label>Password:</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text" /></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
    <div class="column prepend-7 span-10 append-5 ">
        <dl>                
            <dt><label>&nbsp</label></dt>
            <dd><input type="submit" value="Login" id="loginButton" /></dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

login_page.js

```
$(document).ready( 
function()
{
    //login
    $("#password").keyup(function(event){ if(event.keyCode == 13){          $("#loginButton").click();}}); //submit on enter key
    $('#loginButton').click(function()
    {            
        do_login($("#email"), $("#password"), $(".tips"), "<?php echo site_url('dashboard'); ?>", "<?php echo site_url('login/log_in'); ?>");
        return false;
    });
});
```

So the problem here is in the do_login I'm trying to call PHP site_url but it obviously won't work.  It all works ok if I have the javascript in my php inline but that makes the files rather large and I'd prefer separate file.

What I need to know is this even possible?  If so, has anyone come up with an elegant solution to this problem?

Comment: Is do_login() a JS function from CodeIgnitor? Where is it included in the HTML?

Comment: You can have a two global var named `dashboard_url` and `login_url` at the top of your `login_page` file and use that in `login_page.js`

Comment: @Joy Better add one global object for all of the urls `window.Urls = {"login": "<? ... ?>", "dashboard": "<? ... ?>"}`

Comment: do_login() is just another JS function of my own, simply does an ajax login. Didn't think it was relevant to this question as the real detail is the <?php echo site_url() ?> part

Comment: @Andreas thats even better. :)

Comment: @Andreas If I had a global js object with all the URLs, wouldn't I run into the same problem in trying to run PHP site_url() from it??

Comment: @peacemaker You accepted that way as the solution :) It's just an "optimisation" of Joy's first answer.

Comment: Yes, I realized after I asked :)  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the base_url as a JS global variable or even better declare a JS global object with all url's you may need later in your `login_page.php` before including `login_page.js`. Then they will be in a separate container and will be available in any JS code loaded after that declaration, Inline or external.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    window.URLS  = {
      "BASE_URL" : "<?php echo site_url(....); ?>",
      "LOGIN_URL" : "<?php echo site_url(....); ?>",
      "DASHBOARD_URL" : "<?php echo site_url(....); ?>",
    };
</script>
```

Then use it in `login_page.js` like

```
do_login($("#email"), 
         $("#password"), 
          $(".tips"), 
          URLS.DASHBOARD_URL, 
          URLS.LOGIN_URL);
```

Comment: So BASE_URL is in scope in the separate file?  Didn't know that, thanks

Comment: It's part of `window` object itself if declared globally, so can be accessed from any code loaded after that declaration. Inline or external

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to define a JS variable in your HTML - which is used by your JS file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    _Base_URL = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
</script>
```

Then in your JS

```
do_login($("#email"), $("#password"), $(".tips"), (_Base_URL+"dashboard"), (_Base_URL+"login/log_in) ");
```

Comment: In JS you concatenate strings with  `+` not `.`

Comment: Put quotes around `<?php echo base_url();?>` or it will throw errors.